# How to disable graphic login on Github, when using terminal?

Tags: github

I have an issue, that while using Github on terminal, I get graphical prompts for login. I would like to disable the graphical login.

When I am trying to push files to a Github repository, while using Terminal, I get a graphical popup login window (and afterwards password one).
If I press cancel in either of the windows, it gives output shown bellow and allows me to login directly from the terminal (the way I would like to).

> error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass'
>   Password for 'https://Username@github.com':

I am using URXVT terminal emulator on Fedora with Gnome, but the same occurs while using Gnome-Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this same issue of the unwanted GUI login prompt.  Bad form by GitHub for not providing an option to disable it or even telling you about the hook they added.

To disable it, open your system git config file:

```
git config --system --edit
```

Then delete the line:

```
helper = manager
```

That line is to enable a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) for git.